# Javascript: How to insert iterated values ('for' loop) into a function's argument

Tags: javascript, function

I need the call the function 'foo' 10 times and each time the value will increase by one.

Here's my code so far:

```
 var value;
   for (var i=1; i =< 10; i++) {
    value = i;
    foo(value);
```

}

When I conslog.log it it prints the numbers 1 to 10 but the function doesn't run.

Comment: Where is your `foo` function?

Comment: @Help - No, the poster should **not** try JSFiddle. All relevant code belongs **here**, in the question itself, not off-site. See [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), the section with the numbered list, the item in that list related to debugging. Also see [ask]. Please do not instruct people to do something that is not in agreement with this site's  guidelines.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```js
var value;
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  value = i;
  foo(value);
}

function foo() {
  console.log(value);
}
```

> Simple code to call function foo ten times.

```
var value;
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  value = i;
  foo(value);
}

function foo() {
  console.log(value);
}
```